# Select last 3 rows of sql table

Tags: mysql

I want to select the last  3 rows of an sql table. I know I should use `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 3`, but the problem with this code is that it selects the rows from the end. For example, it selects 30, then 29, then 28. But, I need them in this format: `28, 29, 30`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM reset ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
) as r ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this help your problem

```
select * from
(
select *  from reset 
order by id DESC LIMIT 3
 ) t
order by id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
  SELECT * FROM reset 
  WHERE username = '$table' ORDER BY id  ASC LIMIT (FOUND_ROWS() - 3), 3
```

Comment: I tried this code but cause error: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT nobuzz FROM reset WHERE username = '$table' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $resetnum2) ORDER BY id");`

Comment: Try only this:- SELECT * FROM reset ORDER BY ASC LIMIT (FOUND_ROWS() - 3), 3 and check if it is giving the last 3 rows from  your table in ascending order!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
select * from (select * from table order by x desc limit 3) order by x;
```

Comment: I tried this code but cause error: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT nobuzz FROM reset WHERE username = '$table' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $resetnum2) ORDER BY id");`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Select * from (SELECT * FROM Table_name ORDER BY Column_name DESC limit 0,3) as alias ORDER BY Column_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this manual one !

easy and Simple !!

```
Select * From tableName where 
PKCol=(select count(*) from tableName ) 
OR 
PKCol=(select count(*) from tableName )-1 
OR 
PKCol=(select count(*) from tableName )-2 
order by PKCol desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you out to give latest 3 rows data, if you wanna take first 3 rows then `ASC` instead of `DESC`.

```sql
select distinct column_name from  Table order by column_name desc limit 3;
```